# what does MP_RETURN_IF_ERROR do in google's mediapipe code?

Tags: c++, c++17, mediapipe

```
  std::string calculator_graph_config_contents; // name of string
  MP_RETURN_IF_ERROR(mediapipe::file::GetContents(
      FLAGS_calculator_graph_config_file, &calculator_graph_config_contents));
  LOG(INFO) << "Get calculator graph config contents: "
            << calculator_graph_config_contents;
  mediapipe::CalculatorGraphConfig config =
      mediapipe::ParseTextProtoOrDie<mediapipe::CalculatorGraphConfig>(
          calculator_graph_config_contents);
```

I have this code from the demo_run_graph_main.cc file of google's mediapipe. I an unable to understand what the MP_RETURN_IF_ERROR function does. I found no documentation which explains this either. Could someone please explain to me what it does ?

MACRO DEFINITON

```
#define MP_RETURN_IF_ERROR(expr)                                          \
  STATUS_MACROS_IMPL_ELSE_BLOCKER_                                        \
  if (::mediapipe::status_macro_internal::StatusAdaptorForMacros          \
          status_macro_internal_adaptor = {(expr), __FILE__, __LINE__}) { \
  } else /* NOLINT */                                                     \
    return status_macro_internal_adaptor.Consume()

// Executes an expression `rexpr` that returns a `::mediapipe::StatusOr<T>`. On
// OK, extracts its value into the variable defined by `lhs`, otherwise returns
// from the current function. By default the error status is returned
// unchanged, but it may be modified by an `error_expression`. If there is an
// error, `lhs` is not evaluated; thus any side effects that `lhs` may have
// only occur in the success case.
```

```
#define STATUS_MACROS_IMPL_ELSE_BLOCKER_ \
  switch (0)                             \
  case 0:                                \
  default:  // NOLINT
```

Comment: Looks like a macro to me. Why not look at it's definition?

Comment: @Asesh Thank you, I found the definition. But it's still a little hard to understand. I have edited the question with the definition

Comment: @Asesh https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/framework/deps/status_macros.h
This is the link where all the macros are defined